# HTML a href not working even if using Z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

`HTML` - `a` `href` not working even if using `Z-index`. Even using Chrome's developer tools, the div element doesn't show up. How can I fix this?(sorry for poor english!)

```
.cpu, .mainMemory, .auxiliaryMemory, .io, .gpu {
    color:white;
    font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
    border: 10px solid white;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.mainMemory {
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}

.cpu {
    left: 0;
    top: 20%;
}

.auxiliaryMemory{
    left: 0;
    top: 80%;
}

.gpu {
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.io{
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

article {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 0;
}


.arrow1, .arrow2{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    left: 235px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow3, .arrow4{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    left: 235px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(225deg);
}

.arrow1 {
    left: 5%;
    top: 30%
}
.arrow2 {
    left: 5%;
    top: 60%;
}
.arrow3 {
    left: 15%;
    top: 42%;
}
.arrow4 {
    left: 15%;
    top: 72%;
}

.arrow5, .arrow6 {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    left: 235px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.arrow5 {
    left: 33%;
    top: 55%;
}
.arrow6{
    left: 70%;
    top: 55%;
}
.arrow7 {
    display: block;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    left: 235px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 48%;
    left: 25%;
}
.arrow8{
    display: block;
    margin: 30px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    left: 62%;
    top: 48%;
}
.arrow>div:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: white;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(45px, 16px);

}
.arrow>div:nth-child(n+5):after{
    height: 170px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(59px, 24px);
}
```

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CPU의 구조 및 하드웨어 구성</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/hardware.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Black+Han+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Jua&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="mainTitle"><a class="mainTitle1" href="./index.html">CPU의 구조 및 하드웨어 구성</a></div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <ul class="menuBar">
            <a href="./CPU.html" class="menu"><li >CPU의 정의</li></a>
            <a href="./structure.html" class="menu"><li>CPU의 구조</li></a>
            <a href="./hardware.html" class="menu"><li>하드웨어 구성</li></a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <article>
        <div class="hardwareComponent">
            <div class="cpu">중앙 처리 장치</div>
            <a href="mainmemory.html" class="link"><div class="mainMemory">주 기억 장치</div></a>
            <a href="auxiliarymemory.html" class="link"><div class="auxiliaryMemory">보조 기억 장치</div></a>
            <a href="io.html" class="link"><div class="io">입출력 장치</div></a>
            <a href="gpu.html" class="link"><div class="gpu">그래픽 처리 장치</div></a>
            <div class="arrow">
                <div class="arrow1"></div>
                <div class="arrow2"></div>
                <div class="arrow3"></div>
                <div class="arrow4"></div>
                <div class="arrow5"></div>
                <div class="arrow6"></div>
                <div class="arrow7"></div>
                <div class="arrow8"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <nav>
            <a href="https://thedhmo.com:8081" target="_blank"><img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Website-4285F4?style=flat-square&logo=googlechrome&logoColor=black"/></a>
            <a href="https://github.com/froglike6"><img src="https://img.shields.io/badge/Github-181717?style=flat-square&logo=github&logoColor=white"/></a>
        </nav>
            제작자: 주도현<br>
            이메일: froglike6@gmail.com<br>
            Copyright 2022. 주도현. All Rights Reserved.
    </footer>
    <div class="mouse-cursor"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cursor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/hardware.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Code Result]

I used `eventlistener` in `js` to make 'click' event, but it is also not working.

Comment: Can you please explain problem in more detail like what value for z-index you're using and is there any other div, section who is overlapping it?

Comment: Its working for me using your code.

Comment: First, I would try removing `position: absolute` to see if that solves the problem. If not, it could be with javascript. Are you setting opacity? Opacity will not prevent click events from occurring. Are the elements overlapping?

Comment: I edited to see all the code. @AliBhutta

Comment: I removed position setting but it not solved. JS also not working even if I removed this setting. @Rokit

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible example? Your example has a lot of code in it, making helping you a bit difficult - for reference see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example